# Why I cannot modify some registers of BBB using /dev/mem?

Tags: linux, mmap, beagleboneblack

I know from TRM that to modify values in control registers I need privileged mode and this can be done with kernel module in Linux.

However, though there is no special mention in TRM, enabling clock for ADC and configuring timebase clock for EPWM is always failed if I try to do these using /dev/mem.

Why I cannot do these using /dev/mem in user space?

Answer (score 1):

Becaus, as you've already noted, these registers can only be modified in privileged mode. User space applications are not privileged — only code running in the kernel (such as a kernel module) is privileged.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as far as I know, only control module registers (9.1 of TRM) need privileged mode. For example, in ADC case, other operations on registers work with mmap'ed /dev/mem, only clock enabling does not work. This is why I ask this question.